# Is it ok to use http:// inside an URL body?

Tags: http, url

As far as I understand, an URL consists of the folowing fields:

- Protocol (http, https, ftp, etc.)
- User name
- User Password
- Host address (an IP address or a DNS FQDN)
- Port (which can be implied)
- Path to a document inside the server documents root
- Set of arguments and values
- Document part (#)

as

```
protocol://user:password@host:port/path/document?arg1=val1&arg2=val2#part
```

But I've just met an example of using "http://" inside the path part: there is a redirection service (showing ads and paying money for traffic you route through it) which just adds a target URL (in full form, with "http://") to its own. Is it considered ok from standards point of view? Doesn't it break anything? Normally I'd never expect to meet "//" double slash, a colon or a "#" inside a valid URL but on the places they are in the example above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not okay from a standards perspective.

Per [Section 3.3 Path Component in RFC-2396](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt), path cannot contain the following characters - `"/", ";", "=", and "?"`

Usually, browsers encode such malformed URIs before making the http request, which is why it works in practice.

Comment: Yes, they needed to be encoded to be wellformed. And in practice it is a good idea to put the embedded URL as an argument value, so that encoding and decoding are handled transparently.